# How do I assign values obtained from a loop to array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to assign or store the values I get from foreach loop into an array, so that I can use array sort function for the values. Please below is my code. It seems to create a whole new array for every loop with key = 0. And if i place the print statement below the loop, it will display only the last value obtained from the loop. I don't understand how it was explained in 
[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594335/failing-to-assign-values-to-array-from-a-loop)

```
<?php  

  $studen_id = $this->db->get_where('student' , array('class_id' => $class_id))->result_array();
    foreach($studen_id as $row){
    $mark_obtained = $this->crud_model->get_exam_total($row2['exam_id'] , $class_id , $row['student_id']);

        $student_mark = array($mark_obtained);

        // rsort($student_mark);

        echo "<li>";  print_r($student_mark);  echo "</li>";

    }
?>
```

**Output**
[image: ARRAY]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add [] to generate proper array. Try this:

```
<?php  
  $studen_id = $this->db->get_where('student' , array('class_id' => $class_id))->result_array();
  $student_mark = array();
  foreach($studen_id as $row){
    $mark_obtained = $this->crud_model->get_exam_total($row2['exam_id'] , $class_id , $row['student_id']);
    $student_mark[] = $mark_obtained;
  }
?>
```

Comment: 3 correct answers but "Fastest gun in the west" gets my vote :-)

Comment: Also, per OP's question, I recommend showing an example of using a sort function after the `foreach()` loop.

Answer (score 3):

Create an empty array outside the loop:

```
$Array = array();
```

Within the loop add the values:

```
$Array[] = $mark_obtained;
```

After the end of loop test your array:

```
print_r($Array);
```

Comment: Thanks guys for all the answers it worked. Im grateful

Answer (score 1):

To create only one array, use this form:

```
$student_mark = array();
foreach($studen_id as $row){
 $mark_obtained = ......
  $student_mark[] = $mark_obtained;
  ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).
example:

```
<?php
    $student_mark = array();
    $studen_id = $this->db->get_where('student' , array('class_id' => $class_id))->result_array();

    foreach($studen_id as $row){
        $mark_obtained = $this->crud_model->get_exam_total($row2['exam_id'] , $class_id , $row['student_id']);

        array_push($student_mark, $mark_obtained);

        // rsort($student_mark);

        echo "<li>";  print_r($student_mark);  echo "</li>";
    }
?>
```

`$student_marks` is now a flat array...

Regards.

Comment: Ahem, shouldn't it be `array_push($student_mark, $mark_obtained);` ?

Comment: Sorry, I edit my post in order to use array_merge... You talk about the array() function, yeah copy/paste error ;).

Comment: `$mark_obtained` is not an array so `array_merge()` is going to produce an error...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want ...

```
$student_mark =array();
$studen_id = $this->db->get_where('student' , array('class_id' => $class_id))->result_array();
foreach($studen_id as $row)
{
    $mark_obtained = $this->crud_model->get_exam_total($row2['exam_id'] , $class_id , $row['student_id']);
    $student_mark[] = $mark_obtained;        
}

sort($student_mark);
$arrlength = count($student_mark);

for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) 
{
    echo "<li>".$student_mark[$x]."</li>";
}
```